# How to prove basic facts about datatypes and codatatypes?

Tags: isabelle

I would like to prove some basic facts about a `datatype_new` and a `codatatype`: the first does not have an infinite element, and that the latter does have one.

```
theory Co 
imports BNF 

begin 

datatype_new natural = Zero | Successor natural   

lemma "¬ (∃ x. x = Successor x)" 
oops 

codatatype conat = CoZero | CoSucc conat 

lemma "∃ x. x = CoSucc x" 
oops
```

The problem was that I could not come up with a pen-and-paper proof, let alone a proof script.

An idea for the first was to use the size function, which has a theorem

```
size (Successor ?natural) = size ?natural + Suc 0
```

and somehow using that `size` is a function, applying it to the two sides of the original equation one cannot have a natural number equal to its successor. But I do not see how I could formalise this.

For the latter I did not even have an idea how to derive this theorem from the facts that the codatatype package proves.

How can I prove these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I don't know the first thing about codatatypes. But let me try to help you nevertheless.

The first lemma you posted can be proven automatically by `sledgehammer`. It finds a proof using the `size` function, effectively reducing the problem on `natural` to the same problem on `nat`:

```
by (metis Scratch.natural.size(2) n_not_Suc_n nat.size(4) size_nat)
```

If you want a very basic, step-by-step version of this proof, you could write it like this:

```
lemma "¬(∃x. x = Successor x)" 
proof clarify
  fix x assume "x = Successor x"
  hence "size x = size (Successor x)" by (rule subst) (rule refl)
  also have "... = size x + Suc 0" by (rule natural.size)
  finally have "0 = Suc 0"  by (subst (asm) add_0_iff) (rule sym)
  moreover have "0 ≠ Suc 0" by (rule nat.distinct(1))
  ultimately show False by contradiction
qed
```

If you want a more “elementary” proof, without the use of HOL natural numbers, you can do a proof by contradiction using induction on your `natural`:

```
lemma "¬(∃x. x = Successor x)" 
proof clarify
  fix x assume "x = Successor x"
  thus False by (induction x) simp_all
qed
```

You basically get the two cases in the induction:

1. `Zero = Successor Zero ⟹ False`
2. `⋀x. (x = Successor x ⟹ False) ⟹ 
           Successor x = Successor (Successor x) ⟹ False`

The first subgoal is a direct consequence of `natural.distinct(1)`, the second one can be reduced to the induction hypothesis using `natural.inject`. Since these rules are in the simpset, `simp_all` can solve it automatically.

As for the second lemma, the only solution I can think of is to explicitly construct the infinite element using `primcorec`:

```
primcorec infinity :: conat where
  "infinity = CoSucc infinity"
```

Then you can prove your second lemma simply by unfolding the definition:

```
lemma "∃x. x = CoSucc x" 
proof
  show "infinity = CoSucc infinity" by (rule infinity.ctr)
qed
```

Caveat: these proofs work, but I am not sure whether they are the easiest and/or most elegant solution to this problem. I have virtually no knowledge of codatatypes or the new datatype package.